# find wireless-repeater ip (router)

Tags: router, dd-wrt

Really long time ago I set up my dd-wrt router up as a repeater.
It works well; in the summer I place it near the garden and I have wifi in the garden.
I would like to revisit te settings and see if it would be a good idea to install openvpn.

The problem is: I don't remember the ip of the router.
I probably followed the setup instructions on the dd wrt wiki.

it doesn't show up on the management-console of my main router (a docsis3 modem); it doesn't show up if I do an IP scan of the whole class B; it doesn't show as the gateway when i connect to it (wired or wireless).

Any ideas on how I could find the web-interface?

Answer (score 1):

Really really easy...
Connect to the Access Point, open Wireshark and analyze the incoming packet... and then Eureka you will get the IP of the ddwrt...

No need to factory reset...

another tip
check also addresses as:
192.168.100.1 and so on... ;)

with wireshark you should be able to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a port scan (Ports 80 and 443) on your IP range. If you're using a class C (255.255.255.0) subnet mask then it won't take that long.

I don't have any recommendations for software, though, I'm afraid, so you'll have to resort to Google!

Perhaps this:

http://www.radmin.com/products/previousversions/portscanner.php

Edit: Completely missed that paragraph! When you say IP scan, though, which ports were you checking? You didn't accidentally put it on a different subnet did you? I'd be tempted with a factory reset at this point.

Also, finally, have you tried the quasi-logical approach of trying IP addresses near your other equipment. I.e., if your router is 192.168.1.1 have you tried .2 and .3 or .254 .253 - it would be odd to statically set an IP address in the middle of the range.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I use angry IP scanner on port 80; 8080 and 443.  I tried most logical things; 1 to 10,20,30... up to 100 and then 254.